# Is it worth creating separate databases in CouchDB for different kinds of data?

Tags: performance, couchdb

If I have two different datasets in CouchDB,

1. one is infrequently updated (mostly updates to existing documents),
2. another one is written to very frequently (append-only)

Do I gain any advantage in separating them in separate databases performance-wise? Assume the database is regularly compacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience the performance gains are really much dependent on the views when you query the data. I don't see how  write performance would increase substantially by separating the db with frequent writes but, as this would impact the size of your database, I would advice to keep them separately. This would allow to run compacts at different times and overall, if you do have an issue with a database, it would allow you to isolate it and address it faster than all in one single database.